# Запятая перед "и" в сложноподчинённом предложении

Tags: пунктуация

Прошу помочь определиться, следует ли опускать запятую перед "и" в следующем предложении.
**По плану мы должны были к вечеру дойти до городка, где остановились Маша с Артемом(,) и где жил мой дядька.**
"Городок" является объединяющим членом для следующих за ним простых предложений? Меня смущает повторяющееся "где", провоцирующее на постановку запятой. Или все-таки я не так понимаю правило? Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ***По плану мы должны были к вечеру дойти до городка, где остановились Маша с Артемом(,) и где жил мой дядька.***

**Запятая перед «и» не нужна.**

См.:

> **§ 119…** Между двумя придаточными, соединенными одиночными соединительными или разделительными союзами *и, или, либо, да* (в
> значении «и»), запятая не ставится (при этом подчинительный союз или
> союзное слово может и не повторяться)…
>
> *Точь-в-точь такую же жалость вызывала у нее и мать, Зинаида Витальевна, **когда** <…> укладывалась на ночлег **или когда** учила
> девочку завязывать бантики…*
>
> http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=134#pp134

Comment: Можно дополнительное предложение вдогонку по этой же теме? **Таковы были мечты наших футболистов(,) и они с легкостью воплотили их в жизнь.**

Comment: Если первое предложение у Вас  («По плану…) – сложноподчинённое с однородными придаточными, то дополнительное («Таковы были…) – сложносочинённое. Запятая в нём перед «и» нужна. Подробнее см. здесь: http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133